# SWI-Prolog Emacs

Tags: emacs, prolog, swi-prolog

I use SWI-Prolog under Windows 7 64 bits and OpenSuse and I have no problem with Pce_Emacs, (prolog codes or XPCE).
With Gnu Emacs I can't compile any XPCE codes, other codes, using modules (chr, clpfd ...) work.
Is it possible to compile these XPCE codes, and if possible, what does I have to do ?
Thank you.

Joel